# What is `*((char*)ptr+4))` doing?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int a[]={0,2,4,6,8};
  int *ptr;
  ptr=a;
  printf("%d", *((char*)ptr+4));
}
```

`*((char*)ptr+4))` What is the purpose of this?

Comment: DON'T USE ALL-CAPS UNLESS YOU ARE SHOUTING.

Comment: Note that the behavior of this code is undefined per the C standard, don't use it for production code. In particular, the result depends on the endianness of the machine.

Comment: It also depends on `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: The question, in its current form, does not deserve closing. Voting to reopen.

Comment: There's a reason you need more rep to close than to edit, and yet poorly-written questions get closed immediately and edited afterwards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's casting the pointer to be viewed as a pointer to char, then adding 4 to look at something 4 char's later in memory, and finally dereferencing the result. In a typical case where `int` occupies 4 bytes, it'll look at the first byte of the second `int` in the array. That `char` will be promoted to an `int`, passed to `printf`, and printed out.

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` initially points to the first value of the array. `(char*)ptr` casts it from `int*` to `char*`. Adding 4 to this `char*` value increments it by `4 * sizeof(char)` making it point to the second integer of the array, assuming 32 bit (4 byte) int and one byte char on a little endian platform. The outer `*` dereferences it and hence the output `2`.

Had you not cast it to `char*` - as in `*(ptr+4)` -  it would have added `4 * sizeof(int)` to the pointer and hence you'd have gotten 8, (`a[4]`) as the output.

---

Update: have some fun!

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[]={0x00010203, 0x04050607};
    int *ptr;
    int i, j;
    ptr=a;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            printf("%d", *((char*)ptr + 4 * i + j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I got the output:

```
3210
7654
```

If you try this on a big endian machine, you'd get

```
0123
4567
```

Read more about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Examples_of_storing_the_value_0A0B0C0Dh_in_memory)

Comment: The answer will only be 2 on a little-endian 32 bit platform. On a big-endian platform you'll get 0.

Answer (score 0):

since ptr points to the address of a, it

*ptr is the first value of a, or 0.

By casting ptr to a char* and adding 4, the code is saying "take the address that ptr stores, add 4 to it, then print the value at this location.

In this example, it should print `2`